# Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" - no matching controller found

Tags: authentication, symfony

It's a common problem, there are lots of hints but i'm currently unable to solve it. Maybe someone can help me.

My security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    login:
      pattern:  ^/login$
      anonymous:  ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login: 
          login_path:  /login
          check_path:  /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And these are my configured routes (router:debug output):

```
home                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /
login                    ANY    ANY    ANY  /login
logout                   ANY    ANY    ANY  /logout
login_check              ANY    ANY    ANY  /login_check
```

I would like to have everything in a secured area. But I still getting the error mentioned above: Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". What wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Comment out the login firewall lines as well as the access control lines.  Put anonymous: ~ under secured_area: and see what happens.  Once you get it working then you can add the access-control back in.  I don't think you need a login firewall at all.  You should make named routes for all the paths.  Think it's required in S2.3. But login_check should not point to a controller.  The form_login listener intercepts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crazy. There was no error with Symfony. I'm using Jquerymobile 1.3.1 for the frontend and after every login the url in the browser points to http://myapp.localhost/app_dev.php/login_check. I got the right content after login, but when viewing sourcecode I see the error: Unable to find the controller for path “/login_check”. And when I use the browser refresh button I see the classic symfony 2 failure site.

When I remove all the jquerymobile js and css, the login system works as expected. Maybe I need to change the login form from post to some kind of ajax submitting.

Answer (score 1):

In your security.yml you can define the check_path by uri or route name. Please try with route name like,

```
secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login: 
          login_path:  /login
          check_path:  login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

OR
 You can create a custom security check path in you securityController like this,

```
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="_security_check")
 */
 public function securityCheckAction()
 {

 }
```

the you can define `check_path:  _security_check` in your security configuration file

Comment: Thanks for reply. The first one did not work, I get a blank page. The second solution works partially, I now get "The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? (500 Internal Server Error)"... I know that I can fix this with 'return new Response("");' but I thought, that I don't need to implement such a controller??? After login I don't get redirected to "/", I stay on "/login_check".

Comment: Symfony standard package have a perfect demo for this, please check src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php

Comment: plus for remove / in login_check